# GCC ERROR: Cannot Execute Binary File [GCC Compiled from Source]

Tags: gcc, makefile, ld

I am writing an Operating System. I am currently stuck at not being able to compile C code into output files, then further linking them with ld

When I run my make file, this error pops up:

```
/usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -c kernel/kernel.c -o kernel/kernel.o
/usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc: /usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [kernel/kernel.o] Error 126
```

This is the makefile

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard kernel/*.c drivers/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard kernel/*.h drivers/*.h)
# Nice syntax for file extension replacement
OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

# Change this if your cross-compiler is somewhere else
CC = /usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc
GDB = /usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gdb
LD = /usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-ld

# -g: Use debugging symbols in gcc
CFLAGS = -g

# First rule is run by default
os-image.bin: boot/boot.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > os-image.bin

# '--oformat binary' deletes all symbols as a collateral, so we don't need
# to 'strip' them manually on this case
kernel.bin: boot/kernelStart32.o ${OBJ}
    ${LD} -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

# Used for debugging purposes
kernel.elf: boot/boot_32bit_kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ${LD} -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ 

run: os-image.bin
    qemu-system-i386 -fda os-image.bin

# Open the connection to qemu and load our kernel-object file with symbols
debug: os-image.bin kernel.elf
    qemu-system-i386 -s -fda os-image.bin &
    ${GDB} -ex "target remote localhost:1234" -ex "symbol-file kernel.elf"

# Generic rules for wildcards
# To make an object, always compile from its .c
%.o: %.c ${HEADERS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@

%.bin: %.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.bin *.dis *.o os-image.bin *.elf
    rm -rf kernel/*.o boot/*.bin drivers/*.o boot/*.o
```

I have built GCC etc to the path: `/usr/local/i386-elf-gcc`

I am on macOS Monterey 12.4 (Intel - x86_64) and have all dependencies installed

I have tried looking everywhere for this problem, trying different flags and everything, however the problem still persisted

Answer (score 0):

It means that the compiler you built doesn't run on the system you are running it on.  You have to decide whether you want to do *native compiling* in which case you would build a compiler that *runs* on the target and also *generates output* for the target.  This is how the compilers you usually use always work.

If you create that kind of compiler then you have to run `make` on the *target* since that's where you build the compiler to run.

Or, you can create a **cross-compiler**.  A cross-compiler runs on your *local* system, but builds output that runs on the *target* system.

In your case, if you want to compile code on your MacOS system but generate binary files that run on a different system, you need a cross-compiler.